# jQuery Regex Check: No minimum length?

Tags: jquery, regex, html

this is my code:

```
<input type="text" id="Desc" placeholder="Beschreibung (Optional)'"  pattern="^[a-zA-Z\wäöüÄÖÜß\- ][a-zA-Z0-9\wäöüÄÖÜß\- ][\w-.,@&amp;(){}\[\]:;!?\wäöüÄÖÜß\- ]{,150}$" />
```

What is **should** do:
ignore when field is empty (no minimum chars)

But it doesnt work...

What am I doing wrong?

DoJoChi

Answer (score 0):

Try this:  `pattern="(^[a-zA-Z\wäöüÄÖÜß\- ][a-zA-Z0-9\wäöüÄÖÜß\- ][\w-.,@&amp;(){}\[\]:;!?\wäöüÄÖÜß\- ]{,150}$)?"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type="text" id="Desc" placeholder="Beschreibung (Optional)'"  pattern="^[a-zA-Z\wäöüÄÖÜß\- ][a-zA-Z0-9\wäöüÄÖÜß\- ][\w.,@&amp;(){}\[\]:;!?\wäöüÄÖÜß\- ]{5,150}$" />
```

The problem where first of all **w-** doesnt do anything, use **w+** or **w?** or only **w**
Second problem **{,150}** isnt anything use **{10,150}** which means if it is minimum 10 chars.

Copy the regex and pase it to http://regexpal.com/ and you can try it out. Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Hey Ziinloader, can u explain, what w does or stand for? Also, I need this field **optional**, so it should be possible to leave it empty. But  {0,150} doesn't work. Oddly, when entering 3 characters, it validates okay.

Comment: `\w` is the same as [A-Za-z0-9_] meaning a **word**. Try use this regex `^(|[a-zA-Z\wäöüÄÖÜß\- ][a-zA-Z0-9\wäöüÄÖÜß\- ][\w.,@&amp;(){}\[\]:;!?\wäöüÄÖÜß\- ]{0,150})$`. From the start **^(|** means if empty else. So it should allow your regex to return true. ^=start with, (=start word object, |=or else. Hope this helps you out

Answer (score 0):

It seems you forgot to put brackets and a `?` to make the whole regex optional. I'm also pretty sure `{,150}` isn't a valid syntax. It should be `{x,150}` where `x` is a number between 0 and 149.

So, in the end, your regular expression should be something like:

```
^([a-zA-Z\wäöüÄÖÜß\- ][a-zA-Z0-9\wäöüÄÖÜß\- ][\w-.,@&amp;(){}\[\]:;!?\wäöüÄÖÜß\- ]{1,150})?$
```